# Amazon S3 HTTP Headers Allow Sub Domain?

Tags: iframe, amazon-s3, http-headers, cross-domain

I store my newsletters .html files in S3 and I have created a function that pulls the newsletters and puts them into iFrames.

My problem is I can't set an auto height for the iFrames because I can't read the content.

I have a plugin that works if the files are on the same domain. Can I set some headers to allow access from my sub-domain?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about specifically which error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 has a feature called ["Virtual Hosting"](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs?r=8110).

> Virtual Hosting, in general, is the practice of serving multiple web
>   sites from a single web server. One way to differentiate sites is by
>   using the apparent host name of the request instead of just the path
>   name part of the URI. An ordinary Amazon S3 REST request specifies a
>   bucket using the first slash delimited component of the Request-URI
>   path. Alternatively, using Amazon S3 Virtual Hosting, you can address
>   a bucket in a REST API call using the HTTP Host header. In practice,
>   Amazon S3 interprets Host as meaning that most buckets are
>   automatically accessible (for limited types of requests) at
>   http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com. Furthermore, by naming your bucket
>   after your registered domain name and by making that name a DNS alias
>   for Amazon S3, you can completely customize the URL of your Amazon S3
>   resources, for example: http://my.bucketname.com/

Try mapping your S3 bucket to your domain.

See [here](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html) for an example.

> **Accessing S3 Buckets via Virtual Host URLs**
>
> S3 provides two ways to access your content. One way uses
>   s3.amazonaws.com host name URLs, such as this:
>
> http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket.mydomain.com/myObjectKey
>
> The other way to access your S3 content uses a virtual host name in
>   the URL:
>
> http://mybucket.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/myObjectKey
>
> Both of these URLs map to the same object in S3.
>
> You can make the virtual host name URL shorter by setting up a DNS
>   CNAME that maps mybucket.mydomain.com to
>   mybucket.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com. With this DNS CNAME alias in
>   place, the above URL can also be written as follows:
>
> http://mybucket.mydomain.com/myObjectKey
>
> This shorter virtual host name URL works only if you setup the DNS
>   CNAME alias for the bucket.

Comment: I have set up the DNS CNAME but javascript still can't access iframe's height. What can I do?